# How does domain registration work?

Tags: dns, registration, registrar

I searched on Google and Wikipedia a lot, but I could't find answers for these questions.

1) What exactly registrar company do? They update an root DNS and set there IP of my DNS?

2) How come the registrar can update records in the root DNS? How did they get this privilege? How could I get this privilege too?

3) What exactly do we pay the registrar for? Just for sending one request to the root DNS?

4) When I register a domain, am I the real (in the eye of the law) owner of the domain? How do companies (e.g. Google) protect their domain? Couldn't their registrar just say: *"sorry we sold the domain to someone else"*?

I hope it's not kind of an offtopic question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but how is this programming related?

Comment: It is related with programmig. Many web developers had to ask these questions :)

Comment: There are many things that programmers do that aren't programming related, that doesn't make them good stackoverflow questions

Comment: Or replying to more than 3 years old comments :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Registrars job is primarily to coordinate and make sure there are no duplicates in domain names. [ICANN](http://www.icann.org/) manages them. At a technical level registrars (and [registries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registry)) use the [Extensible Provisioning Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Provisioning_Protocol) to achieve this.

They do update the DNS with nameserver information but not the [Root DNS servers](http://www.root-servers.org/) (which is an entirely different area) only the [TLD (Top Level Domain) servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain).

Legally (I am not sure about this, so take it with a pinch of salt) you have a contractual relationship with your registrar and registry, and from there you can take it to courts and so on. They are governed by the country they reside. Registries also have pretty comprehensive dispute policies in case of disagreements of the ownership for example. However, starting with [ICANN](http://www.icann.org/), all these organisations (another example is [Nominet](http://www.nominet.org.uk/) in the UK) have massively policy based working style, and they update them according to the feedback mainly from their members and customers (us).

Answer (score 8):

1) The registrar has a DNS server. It tells the main (called top-level) DNS server owners (for instance the .com) to forward all requests for yourdomain.com to their DNS server. You can also do this directly with the owners of the top level domain (ICANN in the case of dot com I think). But then you need to run your own DNS server.

2) They don't, see number one.

3) They pay a fee to the top level registrar.

4) Depends on your registrar (possibly country), but with proper registrars you do (however read the contract with your registrar).

Comment: 1) "The registrar has a DNS server." No it does not. Or at least it does not need to have one to conduct domain name registration operations. Instead it connects, typically through EPP, to registries. 3) There is no "top level" registrar, each TLD is managed by a **registry**

Comment: "ICANN in the case of dot com I think" No. ICANN has no operational role in the DNS day to day life and does not own any TLD (except `.int` if we want to discuss the point). The registry of .COM is Verisign, this can be checked at https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/com.html and same for any other TLD.