# switching wordpress website from test to live in plesk

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting, plesk

So i am having a problem, there is a website which have been hosted on plesk and currently to access that website i have to change my hosts file in system32 folder and put the IP and website domain name to access that file. Now i want to remove that so that i can access my website without editing my hosts file. How can i do that?

**Note:** I didn't made those settings on that website where i have to edit my hosts file to access the website and the website is made in wordpress.

I really dont have idea what to do because i have always used wamp to use it on localhost. Please Help guys!! thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your website does not have public DNS records and you should create them.

As you want to host it on Plesk server let me explain on example:
Let's assume that you have created a website and called it example.com. For development and tests you used wamp server on your local machine and to reach website you edited local hosts file.

Now you want to move it to production, so what you need to do:
First you should register your domain. You can do it with some registrar like GoDaddy.

Next you need to create this domain in Pleks > Subscriptions > Add Subscription. On this step Plesk will create a DNS zone for your domain on local DNS server.

After that you have two options:
1. Allow Plesk to host and serve DNS zone. In this case you need to configure Plesk server as name servers for your website on registrar side.
2. Use another DNS server, for example provided by your hosting provider, and configure zone for your website manually.

Finally you need to wait until zone will be propagated world-wide and your website will become accessible.

You can read more about DNS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878780/how-dns-servers-work-know-the-ip-address-of-website), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/477314/how-do-dns-servers-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235607/how-does-domain-registration-work).